# How to handle null values in LINQ with multiple where clauses

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, where-clause

I have a LINQ query with multiple values in a where clause. The values in where clause are from Filtering options from checkboxlist. Checkboxlist can return Null (or empty string in the e.g.) and that means I don't need where clause in the query as selecting none on checkboxlist means selecting all. I didn't know how to write one good LINQ that can handle that so I ended up using multiple IF statements with multiple queries as below. I tested it and works fine for now with 2 parameters in the where clause. But in reality, I need more parameters to pass in to the query and it will get messy having many IF statements to do that job. How can I handle that in one good LINQ query?

```
Function FilterCol(ByVal col As List(Of ProductDetails), Optional SelectedCategory As List(Of String) = Nothing, Optional SelectedBrand As List(Of String) = Nothing) As List(Of ProductDetails)

    Dim strSelectedCategory  As String = String.Join(",", SelectedCategory .ToArray())
    Dim strSelectedBrand  As String = String.Join(",", SelectedBrand .ToArray())

    If strSelectedCategory  = "" And strSelectedBrand  = "" Then
        Return col
    ElseIf strSelectedCategory  = "" Then
        Dim res1 As IEnumerable(Of StatsDetails) = From x In col Where strSelectedBrand.Contains(x.Brand) Select x
        Return res1.ToList
    ElseIf strSelectedBrand  = "" Then
        Dim res2 As IEnumerable(Of StatsDetails) = From x In col Where strSelectedCategory.Contains(x.Category) Select x
        Return res2.ToList
    Else
        Dim res As IEnumerable(Of StatsDetails) = From x In col Where strSelectedCategory.Contains(x.Category) And strSelectedBrand.Contains(x.Brand) Select x
        Return res.ToList
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: By NULL you mean DbNull, or VB's `Nothing` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple variable conditions for your LINQ query, consider using [Dynamic LINQ Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). It will allows you to combine the conditions into a string variable in advance based on supplied parameters and then use that variable as condition for LINQ Query - this is something akin to Dynamic SQL in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

This is easier to do using Extension Method syntax.  I don't think doing it as one LINQ statement is a good idea.

What you can do is first create your base query using just the table.  I'm going to do it in C#, but it won't be complex to translate to VB--I don't want to confuse you or myself!

```
var baseQuery = col;
```

Now that you've got your base table, you can start adding wheres based on your conditions.

```
if(condition1 == true)
{
    baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(this is your where condition);
}

if(condition2 == true)
{
    baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(this is another condition);
}
```

So, you can chain your `Where`s together, allowing you to narrow down your query based on the conditions.

Finally, you return your query's results, with the `ToList`.  This avoids the code duplication that you had in your conditions and everything's easier to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Use lambda exp like this:

```
Dim FnValueExists = 
      Function(v As String, a As List(Of String)) a Is Nothing OrElse 
                                                  a.Count = 0 OrElse 
                                                  a.Contains(v)
```

Then in your linq, just test for the value like below:

```
Dim res As IEnumerable(Of StatsDetails) = 
                    From x In col 
                    Where FnValueExists(x.Category, SelectedCategory) And 
                          FnValueExists(x.Brand, SelectedBrand)
                    Select x
```

The main code that determines if item `x` will be selected or not, is that `a Is Nothing OrElse a.Count = 0 OrElse a.Contains(v)` line in the `FnValueExists` lambda expression.

In the case above, if `SelectedCategory` and/or `SelectedBrand` list is Nothing or empty (Count=0), or contains the value, the item will still be selected.

So if users did not select any categories, you can set `SelectedCategory` to `Nothing` or just an empty list, therefore `FnValueExists(x.Category, SelectedCategory)` will always return true.